# Why does window.onscroll lags behind actual scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using an equivalent code to position an element:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    my_element.css("top",$(window).scrollTop() + 50)
});
```

The problem is: during the scroll the element doesn't stay still. It wiggles back and forth, as if the `onscroll` event was not being called as fast as the scrolling. Curiously, sometimes it just works.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `position: fixed` in CSS instead of adjusting the top on every scroll. This way regardless of how quickly you scroll, your heading will be rock steady at one position.

i.e.

```
<div style="font-family: oswald; color: white; position: fixed; top: 50px; ...">...</div>
```

And chuck the scroll event handler altogether.

Or even better use a *class*, `<div class="heading">...</div>`

And in your CSS:

```
.heading {
    font-family: oswald;
    ...
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because the heading is supposed to be placed at "center_y - 200". So when you resize the window it's at a different "top" value - it's not fixed.

Comment: @Viclib - You can specify the `top` value in percentage as well.

Comment: @Viclib - Another option is using `position:fixed` and resetting `top` on every resize using `$(window).resize(function() { ... });`

Comment: It's still not possible to fix it at "center_y - 200" using percentages. Also, if I just dropped that req and used fixed anyway, "overflow:hidden" would stop working, if I'm not mistaken - so every header for each frame would show up one on top of each other. Not sure though, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you *DRAG* and move the scrollbar button to scroll, the scroll event is called multiple times depending on how fast or slow you do that, and during that, each time, the function you've specified on scroll event is called, computed and executed (which may take a few fractions of seconds to complete).

As a work around you can use the CSS position: fixed property. If you must do it your way instead, then a possible work around would be to do this with a slight delay perhaps?

Comment: position:fixed still has the same problem if and only if the thing that has position:fixed takes longer than Chrome's rendering refresh rate, in which case it will lag behind as well. Firefox does not have the problem.